# Canvas API - Update a user login using sis_user_id

Tags: canvas, canvas-lms

I am trying to update an existing user login via the Canvas API. I see that the documentation states you can update the user login using the internal login ID (this is a numeric value): https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/logins.html#method.pseudonyms.update

However, I am wondering if there is a way to update the user login using the sis_user_id or sis_login_id (instead of the internal numeric login id). So for example, the API call would look something like

```
PUT /api/v1/accounts/:account_id/logins/sis_user_id:firstlast123
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your API call would do what you're trying to do, check out https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/file.object_ids.html:

> Throughout the API, objects are referenced by internal IDs. You can also reference objects by SIS ID, by prepending the SIS ID with the name of the SIS field, like sis_course_id:. For instance, to retrieve the list of assignments for a course with SIS ID of A1234:
>
> `/api/v1/courses/sis_course_id:A1234/assignments`
>
> The following objects support SIS IDs in the API:
>
> - sis_account_id
> - sis_course_id
> - sis_group_id
> - sis_group_category_id
> - sis_integration_id (for users)
> - sis_login_id
> - sis_section_id
> - sis_term_id
> - sis_user_id
>
> Additionally, some objects support special IDs:
>
> - Users support `self` to mean the current user.
> - Accounts support `self` to mean the root account for the current domain, `default` to mean the Default account, and `site_admin` to mean the Site Admin account.
> - Terms support `default` to mean the default term, and `current` to mean the term that is currently active according to term dates. A term must have a start date or an end date to be considered the current term. If there is more than one term that's active, current will not be found.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Answers need to be more than links, because the site linked to can vanish or move the relevant webpage.